# Leaving fullscreen in IE11

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Using IE11, if I enter fullscreen mode from the button on the toolbar, then leave full screen mode by pressing F11, the viewer continues to fill the browser window until you press the leave fullscreen button.

I am looking to implement a custom UI, which doesn't have a leave fullscreen button, so want to fix the `MSFullscreen` event handler.

I think the problem is that when leaving full screen mode, `ScreenModeDelegate.prototype.fullscreenEventListener()` calls `inFullscreen()` which returns true.

```
if ("webkitIsFullScreen" in document) return document.webkitIsFullScreen;
return !!(document.mozFullScreenElement ||
    document.msFullscreenElement ||
    document.fullscreenElement ||
    document.querySelector(".viewer-fill-browser")); // Fallback for iPad
```

IE11, so no `webkitIsFullScreen`.  `msFullscreenElement` is null, but the `document.querySelector` fallback for iPad is true, because `.viewer-fill-browser` hasn't been removed yet.  '.viewer-fill-browser' then isn't removed, we appear to still be in full screen mode.

On Chrome it just returns `webkitIsFullScreen`, which is false.

Is there a workaround for IE11?

Comment: We're tracking this issue now. Will fix in the coming versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround it should be possible to patch the default implementation with a fixed version (code below is not tested, it might contain errors)

```
<script src="path/to/viewer3D.min.js?v=2.12"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Autodesk.Viewing.inFullscreen = function() {
    if ("fullscreenElement" in document) return document.fullscreenElement;
    if ("webkitIsFullScreen" in document) return document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    if ("mozFullScreenElement " in document) return document.mozFullScreenElement; 
    if ("msFullscreenElement" in document) return document.msFullscreenElement;

    return !!(document.querySelector(".viewer-fill-browser")); // Fallback for iPad
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // your code
</script>
```

Comment: Yes.  I think the ipad fallback is still broken, but I don't have one to test with.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's still needed. I guess it defines `webkitIsFullScreen` or even `fullscreenElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a [tool for the viewer](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html) which doesn't require patching the viewer3D.js source yourself.

In the ***handleKeyDown*** handler you check for ***F11*** being pressed and remove the ***.viewer-fill-browser*** selector from the DOM ...

```
this.handleKeyDown = function(event, keyCode) {

  console.log('-------------------');
  console.log('Tool:handleKeyDown(event, keyCode)');
  console.log(event);
  console.log(keyCode);

   return false;
};
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this issue is fixed in v2.15.